# Why are my app engine queries not finding my instances?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, app-engine-ndb

I have been playing with App Engine, but I seem to be misunderstanding NDB Datastore queries.
I put the thrown errors next to the query.

Playing around in the Interactive console:

```
from google.appengine.ext import ndb  

class Client(ndb.Model):  
    email =  ndb.StringProperty()  
    name = ndb.StringProperty(indexed=True)  

#instantiated client instance with the parameters below. ID is 6578378068983808  
#client = Client(email = "bryan@gmail.com", name = "Bryan Wheelock" ).put()  

client = Client.query( Client.name == 'Bryan Wheelock')  
#client = Client.query( Client.ID == 6578378068983808 ) #AttributeError: type object 'Client' has no attribute 'ID'  
#client = Client.all() #AttributeError: type object 'Client' has no attribute 'all'    
#client = Client.get_by_id(6578378068983808) #THIS WORKS returns u'Bryan Wheelock'   

pprint.pprint(client.name)
```

The example queries I've made are right out of the App Engine documentation, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Do you do a put then RIGHT AWAY a query? this might be your problem. Look into eventual consistency

Answer (score 5):

### Query

Client.query() returns a Query object.

You need to get the results from it like so:

```
query = Client.query( Client.name == 'Bryan Wheelock')
client = query.get() # first result

pprint.pprint(client.name)
```

or just:

```
client = Client.query( Client.name == 'Bryan Wheelock').get()
pprint.pprint(client.name)
```

### ID

The id is not an attribute of the model but of its key. To fetch the client directly by its id you can do a

```
client = Client.get_by_id(id)
```

---

For you reference, you can look up the Model methods here: https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/ndb/modelclass

Comment: just bringing in what's already in the docs: get() (for just one) or fetch() (for more than one) are usually the way to go when dealing with queries